# Transforming XML document between two schemas differing only in namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I appologize in advance if my description of the problem is unclear or overly complex. I just want to be sure I include all the aspects of my problem.

I have a scenario where I receive XML documents valid for a schema, lets call it S1, looking something like this (simplified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xs:schema
        targetNamespace="http://somename.org/original"
        xmlns="http://somename.org/original"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:imported="http://somename.org/originalimported"
        elementFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:import namespace="http://somename.org/originalimported"/>

    <xs:element name="someElement">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="imported:someelement" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

As you can see it imports another namespace which looks something like this (simplified as well) and references an element from it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
    targetNamespace="http://somename.org/originalimported"
    xmlns="http://somename.org/originalimported"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0"
    elementFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:element name="someelement">
        <xs:complexType>
            ...
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

I also have two other schemas "mirroring" the two above where the only difference is that the namespace "http://somename.org/original" is replaced with "http://somename.org/new" and the namespace "http://somename.org/originalimported" is replaced with "http://somename.org/newimported". The are completely identical apart from that. Looks like this (let's call it S2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
        targetNamespace="http://somename.org/new"
        xmlns="http://somename.org/new"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:imported="http://somename.org/newimported"
        elementFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:import namespace="http://somename.org/newimported"/>

    <xs:element name="someElement">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="imported:someelement" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

...and the imported one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
    targetNamespace="http://somename.org/newimported"
    xmlns="http://somename.org/newimported"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0"
    elementFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:element name="someelement">
        <xs:complexType>
            ...
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

What I need to do is to transform **any** document I receive validating against S1 and transform it so that it validates against S2. What is the most reliable and the fastest way of doing this? I relize that one way is simply using string replacement in the XML-documents replacing the actual namespaces but this does not seem like the most efficient way if the documents are large.

The actual transformation must be done using means available in C# (including the XML/schema/XSLT classes).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: XSLT (1.0) can do the namespace transformation, the validation you would need to do separately. XSLT 2.0 with a schema-aware processor like Saxon 9 EE or like XmlPrime could do both the transformation and validation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do you have any pointers to what a transformation like that would look like? I only have limited knowledge when it comes to XSLT. The validation step is not a problem. The transformation is the issue (I was a bit unclear on that point maybe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an approach like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:input1="http://example.com/original"
  xmlns:input2="http://example.com/originalimported"
  exclude-result-prefixes="input1 input2">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="input1:*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="http://example.com/new">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="input2:*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="http://example.com/newimported">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but I would like to see some sample documents to spell it out and test it. In particular the `elementFormDefault="unqualified"` might mean the other elements inside are in no namespace and the above would copy them with the namespace of the parent in scope which is probably not what you want, so perhaps doing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:input1="http://example.com/original"
  xmlns:input2="http://example.com/originalimported"
  exclude-result-prefixes="input1 input2">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="input1:*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="http://example.com/new">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="input2:*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="http://example.com/newimported">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

is better.

As for supplying namespaces as parameters, I was going to suggest the following approach:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:param name="input-ns1" select="'http://example.com/original'"/>
<xsl:param name="output-ns1" select="'http://example.com/new'"/>

<xsl:param name="input-ns2" select="'http://example.com/originalimported'"/>
<xsl:param name="output-ns2" select="'http://example.com/newimported'"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri() = $input-ns1]">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$output-ns1}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri() = $input-ns2]">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$output-ns2}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but I forgot that in XSLT 1.0 a match pattern is not allowed to use a variable reference so that approach will only work if you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime.

Comment: Thanks alot! I will give that a go tomorrow and report back!

Comment: I tried the first one out and noticed the copy-effect of the no-namespace-elements, went back here and saw that you had already posted a solution to that :). The last transformation worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: I should probably not ask a follow-up here but just a quick one: Is there a way to supply the namespace pairs as parameters to the transform?

Comment: I am afraid the direct approach to use parameters that I tried to outline above does not work with an XSLT 1.0 processor, so it might be better that you post a new question.

Comment: Thanks anyway! It was not critical in any way.